# Wait for all object property values to be true, then continue code execution

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve an issue which involves waiting for ES6 imports. I'm using localstorage to set the values inside of a object properties. First off they all start out as `false`, then as they get imported, they're individually set to `true`. This operation takes less than a second. The problem is, if the code continues execution, it does so before some components are loaded.

I've tried a few different things to only call a `callback` (to actually continue execution) once all values  are truthy, but i just can't seem to come up with a feasible clean solution.

Basically i need something like this:

```
let exampleObj = {
    value1: true,
    value2: true,
    value3: false
}

function check() {
    for (let key in exampleObj) {
        if (!key) {
            // exampleObj[key] is false, so rerun this whole check
            check()
        }
    }
}

function start() {
    check()
    // if check() doesn't rerun, it means no `key` was still set to false.
    // therefor carry on and mount the app
    mountSomething()
}

start()
```

I can't wrap my head around how to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

Some more details to help everyone a bit more.

Basically the premise of this is to enable/disable features on the client side (built with Vue). So it goes something like this:

- Vue router is setup with only a few routes
- App starts by Fetching the feature flags from an API
- If a given feature is set to true, I run a helper method to import the component tied to that feature, then use vue router's `addRoutes` feature to include that route
- In the import `then()` method, i set a localstorage value to true, since i know that the component has indeed been imported successfully

Quick snapshot:

```
const features = {}
const featureChecker = (feature, activity = false) => {
  features[feature] = activity

  localStorage.setItem('Features', JSON.stringify(features))
}

export const configureSomeFeatureRoute = (router) => {
  featureChecker('SomeComponent')

  import('@/path/to/SomeComponent.vue')
    .then(Home => {
      router.addRoutes([{
        name: 'some-component',
        path: '/some-path',
        component: SomeComponent.default
      }])

      featureChecker('SomeComponent', true)
    })
  }
```

After this, a `start()` method is called which is meant to then loop through my localstorage `Features` object and check that every single prop is set to `true` before continuing execution and mounting my Vue app. **This** is the part i'm struggling with.

Comment: Don't use an object of booleans like that, use `Promise.all` if at all possible

Comment: By the way, this sort of code is problematic in that it throws `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: A (bad) workaround is to `setTimeout(check, 50)`

Comment: you should use Promise.all as @CertainPerformance pointed out.

Comment: @CertainPerformance actually tried that too, couldn't achieve something that worked...

Comment: can you include a much more detailed code so that we can analyze the problem carefully?

Comment: I usually create a checking routine somewhere and then trigger an event whenever the state changes.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag - Made an edit containing more info.

Comment: okay. let me check.

Comment: I've added an answer. It doesn't look like your code but it will give you an idea. since the `import` returns a promise, you can just store the reference into an array and use `Promise.all()` to check if everything is finally loaded.

Comment: you don't need to use localStorage and create a function to check if all the imports are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Promise.all`.

```js
let importsContainer = [];


let import1 =
  import ('@/path/to/SomeComponent.vue')
  .then(Home => {
    router.addRoutes([{
      name: 'some-component',
      path: '/some-path',
      component: SomeComponent.default
    }]);
  });

importsContainer.push(import1);


let import2 =
  import ('@/path/to/SomeComponent.vue')
  .then(Home => {
    router.addRoutes([{
      name: 'some-component',
      path: '/some-path',
      component: SomeComponent.default
    }]);
  });

importsContainer.push(import2);


Promise.all(importsContainer).then((imports) => {

  // everything is imported, do something or

});
```

Comment: Used the same concept (but a slightly different approach), and it works brilliantly! Something new i've learnt today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it wrapping it in Promises and use a setTimeout to wait for the variables to be set. Then use `Promise.all`, this waits for all the Promise to be resolve. Then you want do your logic in the `.then` function. Of course in your example you won't `res(1)` but resolve with the values of your localstorage.

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res(1), 2000))
const promise2 = new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res(1), 2000))
const promise3 = new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res(1), 2000))

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values)
  // your start function here.
});
```